# Search for pages on Archive.org by keyword?

Tags: search-engine, archive.org

I'm trying to do some research on a topic where I think most of the original info has gone offline. I was unable to find a way to search Archive.org websites by keyword and show the pages that have that keyword. Is there any way to do this? I don't want to search for a specific domain, I want every website that contains the keywords.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 14 times.

Answer (score 0):

Archive.org has a pretty advanced **Advanced Search**: **https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php**

[image: 0]