# Archive.org search by Title, Date, FullText simultaneously

Tags: search, archive.org

*Is it possible to search books satisfying **1),2),3)** simultaneously in Archive.org ?*

**1)** title contains `food`
**2)** added date is from `2015-01-01` to `2015-12-31`
**3)** contents(=full text) of the book contains `cold`

It is possible to search books satisfying **1), 2)** simultaneously :

[image]

It is also possible to search books satisfying **3)** :

[image]

But I cannot search books satisfying **1),2),3)** simultaneously.

This question may be more about the nature of the website itself (=archive.org) than it is about programming. But, if the website doesn't allow to search like that fundamentally, I don't even have to think about such programming.

Comment: I found this question by looking at the questions with the tag [tag:html]. In this case the question is only about the search feature of archive.org. The other tags aren't related. Ref. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 0):

As of November 2, 2023, The Internet Archive, archive.org, has changed a bit it's design but apparently, the search feature is still the same.

The screenshots look to be showing the basic search. They show the link Advanced Search. It would help if you tried it. The link points to the following URL https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php.

Related

- [Search for pages on Archive.org by keyword?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129773/88163)
- [full text searching on particular site archived via archive.org](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/147898/88163)